# How do I set a global variable in Sinatra depending on the production or development environment?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra's `set` method in order to assign a global variable:

```
set :location, 'Melbourne'
```

I want to update this so that the variable is static or dynamic depending on whether the app is in development or production. I tried this below, which works in development, but not in production:

```
set :location, production? ? request.location.city : 'Melbourne'
```

The `request.location.city` is from the geolocation gem, and this method work fine in production in other situations. Is there something in the `if` statement that I'm missing, or does the Sinatra `set` method not accept statements?

Comment: Please show more context. Do you use set inside a request handler (get/post)?

Comment: no, the `set` method is just used at the top of the sinatra app to set a global var. See http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Comment: Have you tried accessing by using Rack::Request instead of just "request"

Comment: Tried it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request` is not available at the top level, only inside request handlers.

Write a method instead of a global setting, e.g.:

```
def location(request)
  production? ? request.location.city : 'Melbourne'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I thought that might be the answer, but didn't know about the `request` scope. What would be the `request` param passes into the method on call then?`

Comment: Simply:

    get '/foo' do
      location(request)
    end

Check out http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object for details

Comment: Right, though it doen't need the `request` as a param in the `location` method. I dropped `def location production? ? request.location.city : 'Melbourne' end` into the helper methods and it works fine using `@location = location` in any of the `get` methods. Thanks for your help!